# BYOL - Use own windows Server License in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a valid license for windows server 2012 standard.I wanted to use this license in AWS.

Can I opt for dedicated instance or selecting a dedicated host is a must.

While creating an Instance, Is there any option to choose the physical server with two sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of Tenancy options available for Amazon EC2:

- **Shared:** Other AWS accounts might also have instances on the same host
- **Dedicated:** Only your AWS account will have instances on the same host
- **Dedicated Host:** The host is fully dedicated to your use

When launching **Shared** or **Dedicated** instances, the hourly cost of running the Amazon EC2 instance will include the cost of the Operating System.

When launching instances on a **Dedicated Host**, there is **no charge for the instance itself** (nor the Operating System) because you pay for the whole Dedicated Host.

Dedicated Hosts are commonly used for **Bring Your Own Licensing** for both Operating Systems and Software. A Dedicated Host also has visibility of Sockets and Physical Cores that can be used to manage licensing for server-bound software that is licensed **per-socket or per-core**.

See: [Comparing Dedicated Hosts to Dedicated Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/#Comparing_Dedicated_Hosts_to_Dedicated_Instances)

However, Dedicated Hosts are very big and are typically used to run multiple instances on the Host.

**Bottom line:** It is not worthwhile using a Dedicated Host for a single Windows license. Just launch a normal Shared-Tenancy instance.

Comment: So, Your saying we cannot apply license for EC2 shared tendency instance.

Comment: That is correct. See: [Amazon Web Services and Microsoft Frequently Asked Questions](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/faq/)

Comment: Is snapshot option is available in the dedicated host.What is the best backup and recovery?

Comment: How do we automate the backup process in AWS, how to make incremental snapshots? Also, looking for LIFO in the backup process.

Comment: If dedicated host hard disk fails, am I the responsible person as like VPS.Or AWS will restore it for us.Why am I asking is I have doubt because it is a physical harddisk?

Comment: These comments appear unrelated to the original Question. Please create new Questions for new topics.